# How to cluster multi dimensional dataset in python?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, pca

I have been doing clustering using sklearn's kmeans and DBSCAN algorithm on datasets with 2 features. I have to cluster data with very high dimensions say 800-900 I want to know how it can be achieved accurately as possible.

P.S: after some search I have realised that one can apply PCA for dimension reduction but I want to know is there any other way in any other library if not sklearn .

Answer (score 0):

You *can* run KMeans and DBSCAN on high dimensional data.

Also, it is the intrinsic dimensionality that matters. A 900 dimensional data set where 898 dimensions are constant 0 will behave exactly like a 2 dimensional data set (well, it probably takes 450x longer, but that is to be expected).